# onclick() em elementos gerados através de ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Eu estou a tentar usar um evento `onclick` em `<li>` gerados através de um formulário `ajax()`. Eu tenho o seguinte código

```
$(".option").click(function(){
  alert();
  var text = $(this).attr("href");
  window.location.href=href;
});
```

Neste código, ele nem `alert()` dá, o `<li>` tem aquela class e mesmo assim ele não dá sinal.

Daria informação do código `ajax` mas é contra a política do meu cliente divulgar informações por isso é este exemplo de linha de `html` que ele escreve.

```
echo "<li class='option' href='index.php?pg=13&id=1'><small><b>[Texto]</b></small> Nome</li>";
```

Comment: basta fazer assim `$(document).on('click', '.option', function(){})`

Comment: Uma pergunta simples, se este elemento contém um link e você está usando redirecionamento com base neste link quando clicado, poruqe não facilita sua vida e usa um `<a href='index.php?pg=13&id=1'><small><b>[Texto]</b></small> Nome</a>` ?

Comment: Porque todos os `<li>` estão com as classes definidas assim `ul > li{` e se puser um `<a>` antes do `<li>` as classes não serão aplicadas. Eu sei que poderia mudar mas gostaria de saber outras alternativas.

Comment: Na verdade, não há problemas no seu código, o problema está só em onde que ele está executando e quando ele está executando, pois no momento, você está executando essa atribuição de evento de clique antes do elemento mesmo existir na página, por isso não tem como funcionar, então você apenas precisa colocar este seu código dentro do metodo `.done()` do teu ajax, depois que o elemento ter sido jogado na página, que assim ele irá executar somente quando o elemento já realmente exista.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que você pode é atribuir ao `document` um evento `click` na sua classe, pois os elementos estão sendo gerados depois da `DOM` já ter sido carregada, sendo assim não pegará o evento do `click`, faça da seguinte maneira:

```
$(document).on('click', '.option', function(){
  //Evento do click
})
```

Dessa maneira você diz que sempre que for clicado no `document` nessa `classe` ele executa esse metódo!

Outra maneira é usar o delegate() do jQuery, dessa maneira você fala que em todo elemento(div) na classe (option1) ele irá executar esse método

```
$('div').delegate('.option1','click', function() {
    //Evento do click
});
```

Adicionei 3 exemplos separados por uma linha, verifique que no primeiro exemplo a cada clique ele gera um elemento, porém o elemento gerado não tem ação, já no segundo e terceiro exemplos os elementos gerados possuem a ação desejada:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="conteudo1">
    <div class="option1" data-option="1">Click1</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="conteudo2">
    <div class="option2" data-option="1">Click1</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="conteudo3">
    <div class="option3" data-option="1">Click1</div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.option1').on('click', function () {
        var option = $(this).data('option');
        $('.conteudo1').append("<div class='option1' data-option='"+(option+1)+"'>Click"+(option+1)+"</div>");
    });


    $(document).on('click','.option2', function () {
        var option = $(this).data('option');
        $('.conteudo2').append("<div class='option2' data-option='"+(option+1)+"'>Click"+(option+1)+"</div>");
    });


   

   $('div').delegate('.option3', 'click', function(){
        var option = $(this).data('option');
        $('.conteudo3').append("<div class='option3' data-option='"+(option+1)+"'>Click"+(option+1)+"</div>");
   })
 </script>
```

Comment: parece ser funcional, porém não me parece ser uma coisa boa atribuir um evento ao documento todo executando checagens de classe a cada clique do usuário na página... acredito ser melhor só colocar a atribuição como o cara fez só que depois que o elemento foi criado mesmo.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Não era necessário os exemplos mas obrigado pelo esforço tomado :)

Comment: @PauloRoberto Seu questionamento me lembrou que podemos usar o delegate para não precisar atribuir o click ao documento, adicionei outro exemplo na resposta

Answer (score 1):

Para elementos como esse gerados a partir do **javascript** você vai precisar usar o `.on()`

```
$(".option").on("click", function(){
  alert();
  var text = $(this).attr("href");
  window.location.href=href;
});
```

Comment: Removi minha resposta para deixar como comentário aqui, faça o bind do click dentro do seu bloco de success do retorno do ajax.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo acho que seu comentario deveria ser no post e não na resposta do nosso amigo

Comment: @RafaelAugusto, como o colega havia postado o código antes, o restante da minha resposta seria apenas um complemento, que ele pode ser incorporada a mesma resposta, caso o autor deseje.

Comment: porque o `$('.option').click(function(){});` não funcionaria se fosse colocado dentro do bloco de sucesso do retorno do ajax? não vejo motivos para alterar para o `on`

Comment: o erro ocorre se o objeto for gerado depois da página carregada, se voce cria um novo elemento deve redeclarar a sintaxe do onclick apos sua criação para que seja aderida a ele